# How to print the class's information in consoles

Tags: java

When I runnig this code, the file is well saved, but I think the input keeps getting errors.
There seems to be no problem connecting FileStream and ObjectStream, so I wonder what kind of problem there is with the code I made.
How to print the Class Person in the File at consoles?
Thanks for reading, and sorry that I'm not good at English

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Person  implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String tel;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, String tel, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString() { return "{"+name+","+tel+","+age+"}";}
}

public class Address extends JFrame{
    JLabel l1,l2,l3;
    JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
    JTextField t1,t2,t3;
    JPanel p1,p2;
    Vector<Person> ps = new Vector<Person>();

    public Address()  {
        setSize(600,150);
        setTitle("Address");

        p1 = new JPanel();

        l1 = new JLabel("이름:");
        t1 = new JTextField(15);

        l2 = new JLabel("전화번호:");
        t2 = new JTextField(15);

        l3 = new JLabel("나이:");
        t3 = new JTextField(15);

        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(l2);
        p1.add(t2);
        p1.add(l3);
        p1.add(t3);

        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

        p2 = new JPanel();

        b1 = new JButton("입력");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ps.add(new Person(t1.getText(), t2.getText(), Integer.parseInt(t3.getText()) ));
            }
        });
        b2 = new JButton("자료읽기");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ObjectInputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\조의수\\Desktop\\JavaTest\\Person.dat"));
                    Person per = (Person)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(per);
                    in.close();
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


        b3 = new JButton("자료저장");
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                ObjectOutputStream out = null;
                try {

                    for(Person p : ps) {
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\조의수\\Desktop\\JavaTest\\Person.dat"));
                        out.writeObject(ps);
                        out.flush();
                    }

                    out.close();
                } catch(IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        b4 = new JButton("자료찾기");
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

            }
        });
        b5 = new JButton("종료");
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);
        p2.add(b4);
        p2.add(b5);

        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new Address();

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us these errors that you've gotten, or whatever other output you got, along with what you expected to happen? It'll make it much easier for people to help you

Comment: The `actionPerformed()` method for button `자료저장` only saves one `Person`. In each loop iteration you are overwriting the file. Are you aware of this? Do you think that each "person" in `ps` is appended to the file?

Comment: @Abra- Yes, I  thought that each "person" in ps is appended to the file. but I can fix my problem with the Answer Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

When you are **writing** your `Object`s you don't need `for` cycle, you write them as whole `Vector`:

```java
for(Person p : ps) { // <-- no need, we already have all Person objects in Vector
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("..."));
    out.writeObject(ps);
    out.flush();
}
```

andyou are **reading** them:

```java
in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("..."));
Person per = (Person)in.readObject(); // <-- We have stored and read Vector here not Person
System.out.println(per);
in.close();
```

you are basically trying to cast saved `Vector` (of `Person`) to `Person`, which is not allowed.

### Fix

Fix **writing** procedure as suggested above:

```
try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("..."));
    out.writeObject(ps); // Write whole vector at once
    out.flush();
}
out.close();
```

For **reading** procedure do not cast to `Person` but to `Vector` like so:

```
Vector<Person> per = (Vector) in.readObject(); // Read whole saved Vector at once
```

Now you will have loaded all saved `Person` objects in `per`.

Comment: @saka1029 - Yikes. I've got confused myself. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, I can fix my problem. I'm glad that you ask my quastion.